# How to use NSSortDescriptor without key

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nssortdescriptor, nsset

I have `NSSet` of `NSString`s. I want to return alphabetically sorted array of `NSSet` elements with method `– sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`.

I have read `NSSortDescriptor` documentation and still have no clue how to create one for simple `NSString` objects.

What `key` should I specify? Is there a better approach than using `NSSortDescriptor`?

Comment: What do you want to sort it by?

Comment: Alphabetically. No fancy stuff :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find it documented that passing `nil` for the key is safe and means to use the object itself.  So, I'd be hesitant to use it.  You can use `@"self"` instead.

Comment: Can you please post some link to Objective-C documentation, where this is stated? I've been looking around, but couldn't find this.

Comment: It's not documented specifically with respect to `NSSortDescriptor`. It's just that [all `NSObject`s respond to `-self`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCGEBBJ) making `self` an implicit property.

Comment: I see. It is quite intuitive when I think of it this way. Thanks for complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSSet *sets = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Peter", @"Brennon", @"Zach", @"Yan", @"Akila", nil];
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sorted = [sets sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[desc]];
```

Logs out:

```
(
    Akila,
    Brennon,
    Peter,
    Yan,
    Zach
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `nil` as the key. E.g.

```
[set sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]]]
```

Comment: May I ask, is it documented somewhere that passing a `nil` key is safe and has these semantics?